# Как сделать переход на первое фото категории в Swiperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть слайдер в нем есть 2 категории картинок у одних будет атрибут Экстерьер у других Интерьер
(возможно есть вариант иначе их делить нежели задавать каждой картинке атрибут). Долистывая до фоток другой категории у нас меняется подсветка у пункта.

Вопрос: Как по клику на пункт листать до первой фотки соответствующей категории.
Не смог связать SlideTo и атрибут.

Comment: Добавьте воспроизводимый пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Gorotto/pen/XWpBYNY @Crus